# Updating to stable version of nodejs with n

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, n

this is my first time trying to update the nodejs version of a unix server. I want to use it to create a react app, and facing the following:

```
>npx create-react-app test
You are running Node 8.11.3.
Create React App requires Node 10 or higher.
Please update your version of Node.
```

So I have tried to update the version with the following commands:

```
>sudo npm cache clean -f
>sudo npm install -g n
>sudo n stable

installed : v14.15.4 to /usr/local/bin/node
active : v8.11.3 at /bin/node
```

However it seems that didn't upgrade the version, it installed a different version in a different path.

I am not sure if it is possible just to upgrade the version that is already active, I prefer not to do a workaround and just upgrade it directly.

As complementary information if I run n doctor I see the following:

```
>n doctor
Checking n install destination is in PATH...
'/usr/local/bin' is not in PATH
```

As I said previously, what I am looking for is a safe way to update the version already installed to be able to use create-react-app, being able to rollback to previous version easily if something doesn't work, I understand that the way is using n.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add `/usr/local/bin` to the start of your `PATH` (so it comes before `/bin`).

I do not recommend you try and overwrite `/bin/node` using `n`. Something else installed `/bin/node` in a system directory, and overwriting it using `n` could leave things in a mixed and confused state. `n` installs to `/usr/local` by default, but you can set `N_PREFIX` to install to your home folder, for example.

To avoid confusion with having two versions of node installed, you may wish to uninstall the `/bin` version, likely installed by your platform package manager.

Tip: Changing where node and npm are installed is likely to change where your global npm packages are installed. I suggest you list what you have installed now in case you want to reinstall then in the "new" location. `npm list -g --depth=0`